# Inserting Record into Array Parent

Tags: php, laravel

```
array:18 [▼
      "_token" => "D0bWBXif0Dfhe0X5xecliP3NkRKhvYUmjKUzbw2G"
      "domain" => "example.io"
      "promocode" => "123"
      "firstname" => "Jon"
      "lastname" => "123"
      "email" => "e@outlook.com"
      "phonenumber" => "07572070798"
      "address1" => "2 Wayworld"
      "country" => "UK"
      "city" => "Nr"
      "state" => "Bournemouth"
      "postcode" => "dy1 0tj"
      "password2" => "demo10!"
      "securitycode" => "123"
      "card_number" => "123"
      "card_expiry" => "123"
      "card_cvv2" => "s"
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "clientid" => 94
      ]
    ]
```

I am trying to add the `'clientid=>94` to the first array, not create a new array inside of that array, I have tried array push and can't get it to work. what should I do?

Comment: `$array['clientid'] = 94;`

Comment: Its useful if you show us what you did (code), if nothing else it helps explain your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Laravel helper** for that

```
// Syntax
$array = array_add($array, 'key', 'value');
// code
$array = array_add($response, 'clientid', '94');
```

[Check `array_add()` in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-add)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for how to *flatten* your array.
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/14066311) for some methods.

But for your quick need (and in case you don't actually want to flatten everything), you can just do

```
$firstArray['clientid'] = $firstArray[0]['clientid'];
```

(Provided that the client id array will always have the index 0)

(Also, `$firstArray` stands for whatever you call your big array.)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Syntax
$array = array_add($array, 'key', 'value');
// code
$array = array_add($response, 'clientid', '94');
```

Was the best solution! I just found this Helper right after seeing this :)